# Is it still possible to earn hats through random drops?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Looking at my Steam account, I have 412 hours played on Team Fortress 2. My friend gifted me a premium account, but to this day, I have never had a hat or a item drop for me. I read on the wiki that it's possible and I've had hundreds of drops so chances are I should've received a hat or something by now. What gives?

It's especially annoying when you're trying to make a buck on the Steam economy.

Comment: Hat drops are extremely rare, so it is not really surprising that you haven't seen one.

Comment: In my time playing TF2 I only received one hat drop

Comment: Yep. I can think of 2 drops I've gotten in 1200+ hours.

Comment: I got a hat less than a day after this post. It was a Backbiter's Billycock.

Comment: Did you get weapons as drops, but not something else?

Comment: I can't remember ever getting a hat from a random drop. Weapons yes. But not hats. Note however that some hats awarded through achievements (like the Gibus) will show as a 'drop'.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy he says he's had hundreds of drops - I assume they were weapons or crates.

Answer (score 1):

Hat drops are *very* rare. The exact probability is unknown, but it is very small. To find it out, you would need to log your hours of playing over a very long period of time, and not to log the time over 10 hours per week (as it is not counted for the drop system). There is some data, but I don't know if you can actually trust it.

Robot Unicorn says [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/440/discussions/0/828937420196166859/):

> I have 13 idling accounts, and ill talk about what I get in one week counting all of them.
>   I always find something special like objector or name tag.
>
> More likely I find 1 or 2 hats per week, some of my last drops were Fast learner and Bootie time.
>
> My most lucky week was 4 hats + mann co. orange. Sometimes I find 2 hats in same week same account

Another guy says:

> I've got 2 in an old account it had nearly 1000 hrs
>
> All about luck bbg

And one more guy:

> 2780 hours and I have had many. Around 7

So, again, just don't bother and play. Most hats are not worth much anyway. If you really, really want a particular hat, [buy a Key, sell it for metal, and trade metal for the hat you need](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/306611/164914).

Answer (score 0):

In Team Fortress 2 Hat drops are very rare, so that is most likely the problem.

A second thought is that there might be a bug in the game, although the probablility is that the 1st one is the problem.

What to do:

- Check your game is fully updated
  If your game is not fully updated, update it now.
- Continue Playing
  Continue Playing the game. If nothing has dropped in 600 hours, Then THere could be a problem.